Joule thief circuit
I wonder why LED1 is turned on in the Joule Thief circuit and wirelessly connected LED2 is not.
Someone said "In Joule thief circuit the transformer is wound around a ferrite core. This is to make sure that the magnetic coupling between the two coils is strong. In your image you seem to have done this by winding the coils very close to one another. However the coil associated with LED2 is not wound in such a way and so the magnetic coupling is weak, ie leakage of magnetic field from the two coils is weak resulting in an induced emf/current in the third coil connected to LED2 which is insufficient to light LED2."
Is this valid answer? The LED2 didn't light up even if I placed it close enough.


Inductive power transfer is a bit more complex than that. What are the parameters of your coils?  What frequency is your primary running at?

@vir I experimented with the materials provided without knowing the specifications, and as a result, LED2 did not light up. The question requires inferring the reasons why LED2 did not light up without knowing the exact specifications.

If you don't know the parameters of the circuit or its components, then the only thing that can be inferred is that the circuit doesn't work because you can't just attach two random loops of wire to an existing circuit and get power transfer.

Does it work without LED1?

are both leds of the same color?

@fraxinus yes..

@Jens No it doesnt work

Can you take out LED1, use a 220 ohm resistor, and bring the windings near each other?

Is this from a kit? What documentation does it provide? If nothing, what dimensions are the coils (diameter, wire size, number of turns)?

@TimWilliams This was conducted during the university liberal arts class, and when the professor presents a circuit diagram, the students configure and operate the circuit with given elements. There was no condition for the number and diameter of the coil, and the experiment was conducted with arbitrary number of windings. It seems to be a problem that must be solved with intuitive concepts of electromagnetic induction and circuit theory, not numerical calculations. Because most students who take this course only have taken Principles of Physics(Halliday's textbook)

Behavior is "strange", but you can make it work.

Others conditions


I'm not an electrical engineering major, so I don't know even if I look at the graph, but then what's the reason the LED2 is not turned on?

@abeloejmn If you could add some background, such as what technical level of explanation you're looking for, that would help improve answers.

It seems all we can conclude is that, given the turns ratio and flux coupling, there was insufficient voltage to activate LED2.
Note that LED1 does not light if we simply apply a (1.5V) cell to it; the circuit is actively doing something, otherwise there isn't enough voltage (average or peak).  We can conclude there must be some AC voltage on the main coil.
Given the rudimentary setup (introductory physics), it doesn't seem there's much more we can conclude.  If we knew the turns ratio, we could get more than a negative result -- LED2 doesn't light in any case.  If we could choose the receiver coil to have more turns, we could see what ratio is required to light the LED at various distances (or up close (tightly coupled), at all).
If we know that the coils are equal turns, we can perhaps conclude that the AC voltage is more than zero, but less than required to light an LED by itself.  This is an interesting point, and checks out: we have the coil's AC in series with the cell, and if the AC peak voltage is say 2V, plus the cell's 1.5V, that's the ~3.5V required to light the LED.
The polarity of the coil also matters; perhaps we bias the receiver coil with a 1.5V cell itself, and bring it near.  The peak voltage on the transmitter coil might be +2/-1.5V, and we might light the LED in one direction, but flip the coil and it doesn't light.

Then, LED2 could light up if the number of windings around the receiver coil is higher?

@abeloejmn -- Yes... theoretically. The resistance of the wire might overcome the increased voltage gain achieved. Around 2 times the number of turns that are on the primary may be a sweet spot, guessing 1.5x to 3.5x. You can manually add turns to the secondary, one-by-one, to find the best sweet spot.

Well, if your circuit works in the sense that power is being transferred wirelessly, then indeed LED1 is turning off.
You have created an oscillator on the order of MHz (or at least a couple hundred kHz. I don't know your values). But because of a phenomenon known as persistence of vision, you can't perceive the blinking - it's flashing on and off super fast.

Sorry, I don't understand. Maybe because the frequency is very high, LED1 is bright. However, what I want to ask is that if the induced voltage is generated very high in the circuit connected to LED1, LED2 circuit also flows the induced current and generates a similar voltage at the same frequency, so LED2 should be turned on.

@abeloejmn I don't understand. The frequency will be the same on both coils. But that tells you nothing about the voltage or current on either side - the voltage and current are going to be a function of coil properties (geometry, resistance, turns, ect.) and the coupling between those coils. You mention in the comments "it works". Surly you don't mean, "the LED came on so it's working", What DOESN'T work?

@abeloejmn -- No, the voltages will not be the same. The voltage presented to LED2 will be either transformer action, in proportion to windings ratio, or flyback action, which rises to the voltage necessary to light LED2, that is, if there is not a more efficient short-cut to take. And polarity of coupling determines whether transformer-action or flyback-action.

@abeloejmn -- LED1 is clamping the voltage on its side, and there is a reflected clamping on the other side.

@MicroservicesOnDDD Someone said "In Joule thief circuit the transformer is would around a ferrite core. This is to make sure that the magnetic coupling between the two coils is strong. In your image you seem to have done this by winding the coils very close to one another. However the coil associated with LED2 is not wound in such a way and so the magnetic coupling is weak, ie leakage of magnetic field from the two coils is weak resulting in an induced emf/current in the third coil connected to LED2 which is insufficient to light LED2." Is it valid answer?
